# Can a meso compund be rotated in ANY sort of way in order to show its achirality?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

Are there any limits to rotating a compound in order to prove that its chirality or achirality? (assuming that you're rotating about a single bond)

Comment: Usually no, then you would enter the realm of conformations. Some conformation are notoriously unstable, but still you cannot really talk about stereoisomerism.

Comment: Limit is rotation energy - hence existence of atropoisomery.

Comment: Are you talking about bond rotation or rotation of the entire molecule?

Comment: I'm talking about bond rotation

Answer (score 5):

I think what you may be asking is: could there could be a nominally "meso" compound that has restricted rotation about its central single bond, causing it to exist in the form of two non-interconvertible stereoisomers. Example- start with meso-tartaric acid, and make the di-tert butyl ether from the OH groups and di-tert-butyl ester from the COOH groups. Maybe these groups would be bulky enough to restrict rotation. You could mentally rotate around the central C-C bond until the molecule has a plane of symmetry, so it is still a nominally "meso" compound, but physically you could separate the two stereoisomers.

Answer (score 2):

Rotating about a single bond would be a conformational change and not a stereochemical one. Meso compounds are not defined as having rotational symmetry, either way. For example, 1,2-diphenylethane-1,2-diol does not have rotational symmetry since one carbon is R and the other S.  However, it's still a meso compound because its *mirror image* can be rotated to show that it is identical to the original compound.

Comment: There is no need to be sarcastic. Your molecule would  be indeed unstable, but main problem is are you talking about saturated or unsaturated molecule - trans suggests unsaturation - in this case it wouldn't have freedom of rotation around C=C, but rest of molecule's name says saturated

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry for being rude.  I just used that molecule because it's a common example they give in the textbooks.  I know it dissociates, though, but I think that's a discussion for a different topic.  I'm talking about an unsaturated molecule, because *trans*-1,2-dichloro-1,2-ethane diol is (1R, 2S) or (1S, 2R) which are the same *meso* compound.  It's just a common naming convention.

Comment: Hmm, here it's with _trans_ - http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Wikitexts/Purdue/Purdue_CHM_26100/Chapter_04%3A_Stereochemistry/4.3_Diastereomers but I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be, as it's not unsaturated or cyclic

Answer (score 1):

The properties of a molecule don't change upon rotation about a single bond and such rotations are very fast and frequent at room temperature, so you can consider the rotated form and decied the chirality of the molecule.